# "Quadrante", analisar área em volta do quadrado

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um projeto e cheguei a um problema. O projeto seria um simcity 1 simples feito em javascript puro. O problema é que na hora de fazer cruzamentos e curvas eu não consigo detectar o quadrado ao lado no meu grid. Para aprender a como resolver o problema queria que você feito o seguinte: Caso eu coloque um quadrado o quadrado a esquerda fique verde, o a direita fique amarelo, o acima fique azul, o abaixo marrom e explique como fez se possível. A minha ideia era fazer ao clicar para desenhar meu quadrado eu desenhe outros 8 em volta dele pra verificar se tem quadrado próximo.
[image: Exemplo:]

Link do código: http://jsfiddle.net/4Me57/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você já sabe a posição da linha e da coluna, é básico pensar que: (linha - 1) é na linha de cima e (coluna + 1) é na coluna posterior, e assim por diante...

```
    dR(grid_x[i],grid_y[n-1],grid_w,grid_h,'#0018FF');
    dR(grid_x[i-1],grid_y[n],grid_w,grid_h,'#218126');
    dR(grid_x[i],grid_y[n+1],grid_w,grid_h,'#815E21');
    dR(grid_x[i+1],grid_y[n],grid_w,grid_h,'#FFC600');
```

Comment: Porém eu não tenho um quadrado ou posição definidas eu crio ele aleatoriamente em qualquer lugar que eu clique no meu grid. Desse jeito eu teria que ter uma posição especifica.

Comment: Cara coloca essas linhas de código junto com a linha que faz o quadrado preto... Desculpe mas você não entende o seu próprio código...

Comment: Não amigo acho que não formulei a dúvida direito. Eu quero que eu desenhe o quadrado preto, quando eu clique em cima do quadrado preto para desenhar outro quadrado ele desenhe um quadrado azul mas caso eu clique em um lugar longe desses quadrados ele desenhe o quadrado preto.

Comment: E desculpa se estou irritando é que sou novo na area.

Comment: Use a variável `grid_type` para ver se os vizinhos do novo click já foram clicados usando ifs... (obviamente no futuro você vai ter que registrar nessa variável o tipo de objeto que a posição possui e não apenas true / false)

Comment: Pensei nisso também porém quando fui tentar não consegui uma boa lógica teria como explicar um pouco melhor para eu entender?

Comment: Estou no celular agora, mas veja ai no código n+1, i-1... Use isso na gridtype para ver os vizinhos

Comment: Entendi por que não tinha dado certo antes agora! Eu ao invés de por grid_type[i][n + 1] ,por exemplo, colocquei só grid_type[n + 1] fazendo dar errado!

Comment: @user3792106 porque você não parte para html puro, com o uso de classes vai facilitar muito a implementação de  sprites com os desenhos e até animações, veja o modelo que fiz em jquery do seu script e compare a simplicidade que ficou: http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/6q6gq760/

Comment: realmente ficou muito bom. O por que de estar fazendo em javascript é que como estou aprendendo na escola eu preferi fazer pela matéria que estão me dando apesar de ser mais avançado. Estou pra aprender orientação por objeto e já vi alguns sites pra aprender um pouco de Jquery agora é só terminar por esse jeito e partir pro próximo.